# Confused on how to initialize these variables

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a program for my class that finds the distance between 2 integers, but I'm stuck as it just tells me the variables aren't initialized. The code won't run properly. Thanks in advance for the help, here's my code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Distance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter two integers:");
        int a;
        int b;
        int dist;
        System.out.println("Distance between " + a + " and " + b + " is " + dist + " units");
    }
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a substitute for courses and tutorials for learning the basics of programming.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the variable are not initialized. You are *declaring* them, but never assigning them any values. My guess is you are trying to read from the scanner ? If so, you need to use the `Scanner.nextInt` function in order to "listen" to the user input.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Distance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter two integers:");
        int a = scnr.nextInt();
        int b = scnr.nextInt();
        int dist = /* some calculation on the distance between the two integer */ 0;
        System.out.println("Distance between " + a + " and " + b + " is " + dist + " units");
    }
}
```

Please note that this code is untested and might not work first try.